# How to get seamless noise textures from GKNoiseMap

Tags: swift, perlin-noise, gameplay-kit

According to Apple's docs the seamless parameter in GKNoiseMap is:

> A Boolean value that when true indicates the system adjusts samples from the noise object so that generated texture images can tile without visible seams.

But I've been unable to get seamless textures after experimenting with various values for the size/origin/sampleCount parameters.

```
import GameplayKit
import SpriteKit

let noiseSource = GKRidgedNoiseSource()
let noise = GKNoise(noiseSource)
let noiseMap = GKNoiseMap(noise, size: .one, origin: .zero, sampleCount: .init(640, 640), seamless: true)
let texture = SKTexture(noiseMap: noiseMap)
```

This is sufficient code to produce a preview image in playgrounds which doesn't tile. Setting the seamless parameter to true or false doesn't seem to make a difference in the image.  So what is the proper way to get seamless textures from GKNoiseMap?

[image]

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you find a solution since?

Comment: No. What I wound up doing it just using .move on the noise field and extracting a cylinder/sphere from the 3D field.  It's slow, but it gives me what I need and I only need to generate it once.